# Populate table only with users that satisfy a condition?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have an expanded django.auth.User looking like this:

```
class ExtendedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField()
```

This table contains both regular and admin users.
If the user has `is_admin` is `True` he is redirected to a admin page. On the admin page, he should see a table with all the users that are NOT admins. Stated differently, only users that shows up in the QuerySet:

```
p = ExtendedUser.objects.get_query_set()
p.filter(is_admin = False)
```

should be shown in the table.

I'm using `django-tables2` for generating the tables in the admin page, however they by default show all the users.

```
class ExtendedUserTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = ExtendedUser
```

What is the recommended way to render the non admin users only?

*Note: The default Django admin doesn't work for me for other reasons.*

Comment: `ExtendedUser.objects.get(is_admin = False)` was wrong for it doesn't return a QuerySet. Changing to have a QuerySet returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to generate a filtered QuerySet and pass it into to the table as content.

Here is how the `view.py` looks like:

```
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from student_upload.models import ExtendedUser
from admin.tables import ExtendedUserTable

def index(request):
    p = ExtendedUser.objects.get_query_set()
    table = ExtendedUserTable(p.filter(is_admin = False))
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'admin/index.html', {'table': table})
```

The `tables.py` is unchanged.

```
class ExtendedUserTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = ExtendedUser
```